# LTspice LC tank circuit

Tags: ltspice

Difference in simulation falstad and LTspice. I have made this oscillating circuit, which I am simulating. It is simple and it is identical in both simulations. The values are: R=10 Ohm, C=50uF, L=1H. In falstad the output voltage has a sinusoidal wave with a Vmax of capacitor of around 10V(slightly less) which is decreasing over time, while the Ltspice model has a Vmax of capacitor of around 5.2V.

I suspect it has something to do with the transient analysis, but I already stated that .ic(V)=0 in LT spice.

[image: Output Falstad.com]
[image: Output LTspice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after the voltage across the capacitor, then you need to tell LTspice to do a differential measurement. This is done by left-clicking on the left side of the capacitor while holding the LMB down, moving the probe to the right side of the capacitor, and releasing the mouse button. In the example below, the nodes the capacitor is connected to are labeled "a" & "b". The graph shows the voltage across the capacitor as V(a,b) (red trace) and the voltage across the inductor is V(b) (green trace). The graph values are very close to Jan's calculations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's use math to find the true answer. The voltage across the capacitor can be found by using:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\underbrace{\frac{1}{50\cdot10^{-6}\cdot\text{s}}}_\text{capacitor impedance}\cdot\underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{5}{\text{s}}}_\text{input voltage}\cdot\left(\underbrace{\text{s}+\frac{1}{50\cdot10^{-6}\cdot\text{s}}+10}_\text{input impedance}\right)^{-1}}_\text{input current}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Which gives:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=5-\exp\left(-5t\right)\left(5\cos\left(5\sqrt{799}\cdot t\right)+\frac{5\sin\left(5\sqrt{799}\cdot t\right)}{\sqrt{799}}\right)\tag2$$

It is at a maximum when:

$$\hat{t}=\frac{\pi}{5\sqrt{799}}\approx0.0222\space\text{s}\tag3$$

And at that time we have a voltage of:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(\hat{t}\right)=5\left(1+\exp\left(-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{799}}\right)\right)\approx9.47406\space\text{V}\tag4$$

Comment: Thank you for your time and calculation. Apparently it is correct, but I don't fully understand which formulas/way of thinking you use. I think you may be using KVL in (1).But this will give something in the lines of 5/s = I(t)*((1/50e-6)+s+10), which is not the same thing as you have.If you would do it via the formula V=i/c∫i(t)dt, I do not understand how your imput current is equal to voltage **times** impedance. Also is step 3 based of a formula to find the maximum? If I am missing some theory, I would love to know what since I have been trying to figure your way of thinking out for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that v(vc1)= 0 is not the same as v(C1)=0 ...

[image]